# Cannot connect to iTunes Store

Tags: testing, in-app-purchase

The older version of our app does not support InApp. However, we have included the feature in the new version. We are testing it in the sandboxed environment, by creating a test user as specified in the InApp documentation.  Deleting the old version and then adding the new version works. But the problem is, if we update the existing version(that does not support InApp) to the current one (which supports InApp) and try to purchase, it puts up an alert with "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" message. How can we solve this? Is this happening because of the sandboxed test environment?

Comment: Am seeing a similar issue, but I think it is all users not just upgrades